# How to manipulate images at the pixel level in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, image-manipulation

How do I manipulate images at the pixel level in C#?

I need to be able to read/modify each bitmap pixel RGB values separately.

A code sample would be appreciated.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you want speed, then [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits.aspx). <strike>See here for a good walkthrough by Bob Powell</strike>. If you just want to edit a few, then [GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx)/[SetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx) should do what you want.

Comment: nice. I had never bothered looking into going beyond set/get pixel. Thanks for the links.

Comment: What Bob Powell doesn't tell you is that you don't actually need to deal with pointers in C#. Have a look at LockBits in the MSDN library, there's a sample that copies the memory to a managed array where the method is not marked as unsafe, and therefore the application does not have to be unsafe :)

Comment: XNA users beware, the XBox360 .NET CF does not support the System.Drawing library, which is where LockBits resides. So managed DirectX is likely your only option (thanks Ash).

Comment: Site linked to as "here" is down.

Comment: The site linked in "here" is now a message box pop virus scam.

Answer (score 16):

A sample code routine (I use this for simple merge and compare functionality. It takes two images and produces a third greyscale image showing the differences between the two images as a greyscale tone level. The darker it is, the more the diff.):

```
    public static Bitmap Diff(Bitmap src1, Bitmap src2, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap diffBM = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            //Get Both Colours at the pixel point
            Color col1 = src1.GetPixel(x1 + x, y1 + y);
            Color col2 = src2.GetPixel(x2 + x, y2 + y);

            // Get the difference RGB
            int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
            r = Math.Abs(col1.R - col2.R);
            g = Math.Abs(col1.G - col2.G);
            b = Math.Abs(col1.B - col2.B);

            // Invert the difference average
            int dif = 255 - ((r+g+b) / 3);

            // Create new grayscale RGB colour
            Color newcol = Color.FromArgb(dif, dif, dif);

            diffBM.SetPixel(x, y, newcol);

        }
    }

    return diffBM;
}
```

[Marc's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190385/how-to-manipulate-images-at-pixel-level-in-c/190395#190395) notes LockBits and using that to modify the image directly in memory. I would suggest looking at that rather than what I have posted if performance is a concern. Thanks Marc!

Comment: As was probably already mentioned multiple times, though, `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` are notoriously slow. `Bitmap.LockBits` in combination with `Marshal.Copy` can achieve the same thing, but gets the data out in bulk rather than pixel per pixel, which makes it loads faster.

Answer (score 5):

System.Drawing.Bitmap has a GetPixel(int x, int y) public method that returns a System.Drawing.Color structure.  That struct has byte members R, G, B, and A, which you can modify directly, and then call SetPixel(Color) on your Bitmap again.
Unfortunately, that's going to be relatively slow, but it's by the easiest way to do it in C#.  If you are working with individual pixels a lot and find the performance is lacking, and you need something faster, you can use LockBits...  It's a lot more complicated though, as you need to understand the bit structure for that color depth and type, and work with the bitmap's stride and what not... so if you find it's necessary, make sure you find a good tutorial!  There are several out there on the web, Googling "C# LockBits" will get you a half dozen that are worth a read.

Answer (score 3):

If performance is critical, another alternative to LockBits is managed DirectX.

See the earlier Stack Overflow question *[Rendering graphics in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230/rendering-graphics-in-c#58242)* for more information.

Like Lockbits you will need to use the unsafe keyword/compiler switch, but you get high performance pixel level access.

You also get higher performance screen rendering via DirectX backbuffering, when compared with using the normal Bitmap class and PictureBox control.

Comment: Managed DirectX is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The code listed below contains a bare bone example on how to create a pixel image editor using the C# programming language on Microsoft Visual Studio 2022.

```
namespace GreekPicturePixelEditor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int X1 = 0;  // picture box 1 mouse click X position
        private int Y1 = 0;  // picture box 1 mouse click y position
        private bool mousePress = false;  // is left mouse pressed in picture box 2
        private Bitmap statueBitmap;
        private SolidBrush brush;
        private Pen pen;
        private Rectangle rec;
        private Color color;
        private const int pSize = 20;  // pixel size

        // Step 1. Create first picture box 1 at least 512x512 pixel
        //         Create second picture box 2 at least 32x32 pixel
        //         Create a 512x512 bitmap image using MS Paint
        //         Load and display statue bitmap on picture box 1
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            statueBitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\VS2022\Pic\Greek512x512.bmp");
            pictureBox1.Image = statueBitmap;
        }

        // Step 2. Save X1,Y1 mouse coordinate when user click on picture box 1
        private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            X1 = e.X;    // Save X1, Y1 mouse coordinate when user click on picture box 1
            Y1 = e.Y;
            pictureBox2.Refresh();  // force re-draw picture box 2
        }

        // Step 3. Create a 32x32 pixel grid on picture box 2. When user click on 
        // picture box 1, a pixel grid is created based on the X1,
        // Y1 coordinate of picture box 2.  In other words, 32x32 bitmap image
        // is cloned starting at X1,Y1 position in picture box 1 to picture box 2.
        private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            for( int px = 0; px < 31; px++ )
            {
                for( int py = 0; py < 31; py++ )
                {
                    color = ((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).GetPixel( X1 + px, Y1 + py );
                    brush = new SolidBrush( color );
                    pen = new Pen( Form1.DefaultBackColor );
                    rec = new Rectangle( px * pSize, py * pSize, pSize, pSize );
                    g.FillRectangle( brush, rec );
                    g.DrawRectangle( pen, rec );
                }
            }
        }

        // Step 4.  Handle mouse events when drawing picture box 2 with a mouse
        private void pictureBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mousePress = false;
        }

        // Step 4.  Handle mouse events when drawing picture box 2 with a mouse
        private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if( e.Button == MouseButtons.Left )
            {
                mousePress = true;
                int X2 = e.X / 20;  // Normalized the mouse position X and Y of picture box 2
                int Y2 = e.Y / 20;
                ((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).SetPixel( X1 + X2, Y1 + Y2, System.Drawing.Color.Red );
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
                pictureBox2.Refresh();
            }

        }

        // Step 4.  Handle mouse events when drawing picture box 2 with a mouse
        private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if( mousePress )
            {
                int X2 = e.X / 20;  // Normalized the mouse position X and Y of picture box 2
                int Y2 = e.Y / 20;
                ((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).SetPixel( X1 + X2, Y1 + Y2, System.Drawing.Color.Red );
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
                pictureBox2.Refresh();
            }
        }

        // Step 5. Deallocate memory to the system
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            statueBitmap.Dispose();
            brush.Dispose();
            pen.Dispose() ;
        }
    }
}
```