# How to detect the color of a pixel on the monitor in C#?

Tags: c#, colors

I need to detect the color of a pixel on my monitor. How do I retrieve it on coordinate (x,y) in C#?

Comment: duplicate, see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483928/how-to-read-the-color-of-a-screen-pixel

Comment: You don't need C#. Just use a magnifying glass :)

Answer (score 5):

Use Graphics.CopyFromScreen to copy a 1x1 bitmap, Bitmap.GetPixel() to get its color.

Comment: Thank you. That seems like an easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

First Import these Dlls

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]    
    static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern Int32 ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetPixel(IntPtr hdc, int nXPos, int nYPos);
```

Then write this method GetPixelColor(x,y);

```
      static public System.Drawing.Color GetPixelColor(int x, int y)
      {
       IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
       uint pixel = GetPixel(hdc, x, y);
       ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
       Color color = Color.FromArgb((int)(pixel & 0x000000FF),
                    (int)(pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
                    (int)(pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
       return color;
      }
```

Call the method Color clr= GetPixelcolor(50,50);

Answer (score 1):

First, capture the screen.

```
Rectangle screenRegion = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds;
Bitmap screen = new Bitmap(screenRegion.Width, screenRegion.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Graphics screenGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenBitmap);
screenGraphics.CopyFromScreen(screenRegion.Left, screenRegion.Top, 0, 0, screenRegion.Size);
```

Then, [get the pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190385/how-to-manipulate-images-at-pixel-level-in-c/190395#190395) from the bitmap.

Comment: Note that it works only with the primary monitor. If you need to capture a pixel from other monitors, you have to change the zero index at the first line of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use winapi `GetPixel(...)`