# manipulate images at pixel level in C#

Tags: c#, image, ppm

I have a ppm file and I figured out how to mirror the image from the middle but I can't figure out how to horizontally flip it.
this is the code for the mirror function:

{R[x][y]=R[WIDTH-x][y];
 G[x][y]=G[WIDTH-x][y];
 B[x][y]=B[WIDTH-x][y];}}

the horizontal flip function should look almost the same as above. but achieve a flipped image.

Comment: Is this homework? It sounds like homework..

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190385/how-to-manipulate-images-at-pixel-level-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Drawing.Bitmap

- GetPixel()
- SetPixel()

[The MSDN Documentation for System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx)