# library for editing photos

Tags: c#, image-processing

I want to implement an algorithm for compressing BMP images. What library/sdk would you recommend for helping with reading a picture's pixels, and creating an image pixel by pixel?

Comment: What is it you'd want to do? Do you want to compress BMP's to lower the file size?

Comment: Are you studing a new compression algorithm? If no, you could use conversion to JPG inside C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this tutorial. this will help you to do normal jobs with images in a tutorial format using C#:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-rotate

for working with images in pixel level see this thread :

[How to manipulate images at the pixel level in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190385/how-to-manipulate-images-at-pixel-level-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

System.Drawing.Imaging (GDI+) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx

Could help you... It has functionality to save with saveoptions and encodings that will allow for compression.