# Manipulating images at pixel level in c# to decode it in to text info if it contains?

Tags: c#, image, encoding

> How can we get the info from an image if it contains by calculating
>   the no of pixels and there arrangement.

Comment: Very low effort. This is not an expert question. Try google first and try yourself.

Comment: this reminds me of a particular Queen song...

Comment: Just go to pixel level and edit it. :P 
Jokes apart [What have you tried till now ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Please search a bit. [MSDN Bitmap.LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the Bitmap class in .Net

Here a nice example: [Image Processing for Dummies with C# and GDI+ Part 1 - Per Pixel Filters](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1989/Image-Processing-for-Dummies-with-C-and-GDI-Part-1)

Also the following **[StackOverflow (Question: How to manipulate images at pixel level in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190385/how-to-manipulate-images-at-pixel-level-in-c)** provides already an answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Bitmap (System.Drawing)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap) class. Then, to manipulate pixels, use the methods [GetPixel()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel) and [SetPixel()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel). But if you want a faster access to the pixels, read this article: [Using the LockBits method to access image data](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx) by *Bob Powell* that exploits pointers, compiling with [unsafe code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of manipulating pixel data using pointers.

```
unsafe
{
int red, blue, green;
editImage = new Bitmap("image.jpg");
editWidth = editImage.Width;
editHeight = editImage.Height;
data = editImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, editWidth, editHeight), 
ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
byte* dataPtr = (byte*)data.Scan0;
h = trackBar1.Value / 60.0;
D = 1 - Math.Abs((h % 2) - 1);

if (h >= 0 && h < 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < editHeight; i++)
    {
        offsetStride = i * data.Stride;
        for (int j = 0; j < editWidth; j++)
        {
            blue = dataPtr[(j * 3) + offsetStride];
            green = dataPtr[(j * 3) + offsetStride + 1];
            red = dataPtr[(j * 3) + offsetStride + 2];

            if (green > blue) max = green;
            else max = blue;
            if (red > max) max = red;

            if (green < blue) min = green;
            else min = blue;
            if (red < min) min = red;

            s = (max == 0) ? 0 : 1d - (1d * min / max);
            v = max / 255d;

            C = v * s;
            X = C * D;
            E = v - C;

            dataPtr[(j * 3) + offsetStride] = (byte)(min);
            dataPtr[(j * 3) + offsetStride + 1] = (byte)((X + E) * 255);
            dataPtr[(j * 3) + offsetStride + 2] = (byte)(max);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This just changes the hue of an image.  For any reasonably large image > 100x100 pixels, don't bother using GetPixel or SetPixel unless performance doesn't matter.