# Is it possible to get mouse coordinates of a color on the screen?

Tags: c#, .net

Say there is an orange circle somewhere visible on my computer monitor (any application). How can I search the screen for orange, then get the mouse coordinates of that orange circle (doesn't have to be in the center of the circle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first need to do a `ScreenCapture`, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-sharp-capture-screenshot-of-active-window) for more info. Then, you want to read the resulting image, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190385/how-to-manipulate-images-at-pixel-level-in-c) for suggestions for `LockBits` and `GetPixel`. Then, simply compare the pixel values with the color you are looking for. You will then get the X/Y coordinates of the **pixel**, no **mouse** is involved whatsoever.

Comment: I can set the cursor position with the coordinates of said pixel?

Comment: @leetbit yep, if you're not at ease with pinvoke, check this project, it's as simple as `Mouse.Move(X, Y);` http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117657/InputManager-library-Track-user-input-and-simulate