# how to change the color of an image directly in the browser?

Tags: javascript, css, browser, svg

Thanks for your time. We sell many 3D printing products in MANY colors, as a result we have to create a PNG (or JPG) image file for each fricking color we offer, therefore if we have 10 products on 10 colors it means 100 PNG images files we have to export.

My question is: is there any way to change the color of the image on the fly in the client side? For instance, if the user choose one color then the object changes its color without loading a new img-file

is SVG file created for that purpose? (am I telling something stupid? :P)

Usually each image is just one color with shades of gray, example:

[image]

Comment: If they're created as SVG I believe you have the option to change the colors if you load them as such. As images you're extremely limited. The closest thing that fits is the new css3 filter property but support is limited and it's not exactly what you're looking for. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherMarshall , do you know what is the SVG option you are talking about? or do maybe an example? thanks!

Comment: Something like this? http://www.algosome.com/articles/drawing-javascript-graphics-svg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all images are monochrome, you can draw the white version of the image on canvas and alter the pixel colours by multiplying with the desired colour (e.g., (1.0, 0.0, 0.0) for red).

Some example filters:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/

You do need html5 / canvas support though for this to work, so it depends on the use case.

Comment: Thanks @Turiphro, I think this is the way I go. Here is exactly what I need: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_getimagedata2

Answer (score 3):

Remove the color from the image leaving a transparency. When use the color on the background on the HTML element of the image wrapper so that it can blend in with the image.

Comment: That's a super interesting idea. Wouldn't the background wrapper need to fit the image edges though? e.g. be the shape of the image/product.

Comment: No if your product have white (or any other color) on the actual image background

Comment: Oh! so just the product itself is transparent with white edges! Great idea!

Comment: css3 filters should be able to do that! Greyscale/opacity combination. Wouldn't be perfect, but possibly better than creating all those images. But the final result should still be super close to what the actual product will be so I wonder.

Comment: There's also a shortcut in Photoshop that would greyscale the image easily since they'd need at least one reference anyway.

Comment: You can get the blue colored product and convert the blue color to transparent as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, I do use html5 canvas, so the other answer fits my needs, but thanks for your time :) and I think is a good also as well using the transparency ;)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using some server-side code.
I would manipulate the images with asp.net/c# (php or the language of your choice) and then call it on the client with a jquery ajax call.

Server-side languages can manipulate images easily.
Maybe this post can help you: [How to manipulate images at the pixel level in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190385/how-to-manipulate-images-at-pixel-level-in-c)

Comment: Attempting to persuade the OP to use a different approach than he has *explicitly* stated he wishes to use would probably be better suited as a comment on the question, seeing as "use server-side code" is not an *answer* to "how can I do this using client-side code?"

Comment: That's really one of the most consistent ways to do it in their defense. Browser based color changing is super fickle.

Comment: I respect your thoughts, but my answer was based on what the big sites and e-commerces do all over internet.
Changing the color on client side will probably bring him cross-browser problems.
In addition you can't actually "change the color" on client-side. As you need to manipulate the bits to do that

Comment: Nonetheless, that does not make it a valid answer to the question. Furthermore, with regards to cross-browser issues, that is precisely the reason why developers gracefully degradation or progressively enhance content. The OP may very well have already figured out the server-side implementation, and could be looking for an **enhanced** approach for visitors whose browsers are sufficiently capable.

Comment: No problem. I'm happy that he found a solution. Hope my answer (even if it's wrong) help other people across internet. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer and I made a jsfiddle Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/pys565at/

I used the layer option from library http://filtrr.me/ that changes monochrome images using canvas HTML5 (it does NOT! use WebGl, what is nice).

```
Filtrr2("#myImageID", function () {
    // Create a duplicate of the image
    var dup = this.dup();
    dup.fill(0, 128, 55); // change image to green
    this.contrast(100)
    .saturate(-100) // bw
    .layer("overlay", dup) // use this layer
    .render();
});
```

[image]