# What is the fastest way to draw an Image on another image?

Tags: gdi+, performance, drawimage

I have 3 Bitmap point .

```
Bitmap* totalCanvas = new Bitmap(400, 300, PixelFormat32bppARGB);  // final canvas
Bitmap* bottomLayer  = new Bitmap(400, 300,PixelFormat32bppARGB); // background
Bitmap* topLayer = new Bitmap(XXX); // always changed.
```

**I will draw complex background on bottomLayer. I don't want to redraw complex background on totalCanvas again and again, so I stored it in bottomLayer.**

TopLayer changed frequently.
I want to draw bottomLayer to totalCanvas. Which is the fastest way?

```
Graphics canvas(totalCanvas); 
canvas.DrawImage(bottomLayer, 0, 0);  step1
canvas.DrawImage(topLayer ,XXXXX);   step2
```

I want step1 to be as fast as possible. Can anyone give me some sample?
Thanks very much!

Thanks for unwind's answer. I write the following code:

```
Graphics canvas(totalCanvas); 
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
canvas.DrawImage(bottomLayer, 0,0);
}
```

this part takes 968ms... it is too slow...

Comment: are bottoLayer dimensions allways the same as totalCanvas Dimentions?
If so , why creating two bitmaps?

Comment: Thanks, I added the reason in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible (and it looks like it from your code), using DrawImageUnscaled will be significgantly faster than DrawImage.  Or if you are using the same image over and over again, create a TextureBrush and use that.

The problem with GDI+, is that for the most part, it is unaccelerated.  To get the lightening fast drawing speeds you really need GDI and BitBlt, which is a serious pain in the but to use with GDI+, especially if you are in Managed code (hard to tell if you are using managed C++ or straight C++).

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230/rendering-graphics-in-c) for more information about graphics quickly in .net.